# How to revise the visualization_utils.py to show the class_name in chinese

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

In visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array function:

```
       class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
          if(class_name == 'a'):
                class_name = '我我我我'
```

In draw_bounding_box_on_image function:

```
try:
    font = ImageFont.truetype('Arial.ttf', 40)
  except IOError:
    font = ImageFont.load_default()

  # If the total height of the display strings added to the top of the bounding
  # box exceeds the top of the image, stack the strings below the bounding box
  # instead of above.
  display_str_heights = [font.getsize(ds)[1] for ds in display_str_list]
  # Each display_str has a top and bottom margin of 0.05x.
  total_display_str_height = (1 + 2 * 0.05) * sum(display_str_heights)

  if top > total_display_str_height:
    text_bottom = top
  else:
    text_bottom = bottom + total_display_str_height
  # Reverse list and print from bottom to top.
  for display_str in display_str_list[::-1]:
    text_width, text_height = font.getsize(display_str)
    margin = np.ceil(0.05 * text_height)
    draw.rectangle(
        [(left, text_bottom - text_height - 2 * margin), (left + text_width,
                                                          text_bottom)],
        fill=color)
    draw.text(
        (left + margin, text_bottom - text_height - margin),
        display_str,
        fill='black',
        font=font)
    text_bottom -= text_height - 2 * margin
```

But the class_name will show:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GfUC.png)

How can I save this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved use MSfont.ttf in above try...